# How to align and order images displayed from mysql

Tags: php, image, mysqli

I'm making A website that is linked to a database. The database contains images that I have displayed on the website okay. The issue I'm having is aligning them and making it look tidy. What would be the best method to look into?

```
include 'NavigationBar.php';
echo ' MENS<br>';
$query="SELECT * FROM Trainers";
$results=mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
    echo $row['Brand'].'<img src="./images/'.$row['Image'].'" width="200" height="200" "</br> ';
}
```

**Edit:**

At the moment, it prints all the images from the database but in one long list. I would like to be able to assign a certain number of images to each row then move on the next row and so on.

Comment: Way too broad a question. It's anybody's guess as to the layout. Look up HTML/CSS layouts.

Comment: what is your problem actually, are they looking ugly, or you just want them next to each other ? Sorry if I didnt understand something

Comment: My poor question asking sorry. At the moment it prints all the images from the database but in one long list. Id like to be able to assign a certain number of images to each row then move on the next row and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html list tag and then make it tidy by adding css codes

```
<ul>
  <li><img src=""></li>
  <li><img src=""></li>
  <li><img src=""></li>
</ul>
```

and http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp

Answer (score 0):

I am currently not able to test it out, but i guess it should be ok.
Just let me know if there are problems

```
<style type="text/css">

.my-images-list {

    list-style: none;
}
```

.my-images-list li{

```
    float: left;
}

</style>

<?php
    $html = '<ul class="my-images-list>';

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){

        $html.='
            <li>
                <img src="./images/'.$row['Image'].'" width="200" height="200" />  
            </li>
        ';
    }

    echo $html.'<ul>';
?>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: It works the same as it did before really how would i go about putting a certain number of images on each row before it moves to the next?